# Organisation Details Recognition

Tags: nlp

I am trying to write a company's details parser that can split text like the following into it's constituent parts:

> THALES LAND AND JOINT SYSTEMS
>
> Total Signature Management
>
> Wookey Hole Road
>
> Wells
>
> Somerset
>
> BA5 1AA
>
> Tel: +44(0)1749 682384
>
> Fax: +44 (0)1749 682235

The problem I am having is, how I can tell that "Total Signature Management" is not actually part of the address?  Normally, a company will display its name "THALES LAND AND JOINT SYSTEM" and line 2 would normally be the first part of the address.

In the case above, the company name is followed by a non address part, is there anyway to tell the difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the probability of Address<->Description based on the occuring words. In this example it's quite obvious: the "road" line is much more likely to be part of an address than the "management" line.

This should work nicely if the non-address part will only appear after the company name. If it's possible that the non-address parts can be found somewhere in the text, it's getting near to impossible to separate them without further information.

Maybe you want to take a look on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046451/algorithm-to-match-natural-text-in-mail) I asked yesterday.

**Edit**: You could create a statistical model based on previous categorized address-parts (the ones you are sure, that they are addresses ;) ).